# Can you add Nth child to JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I was wondering if it was possible to add some sort of Nth Child to this piece of code?

```
  $(function() {
    var count = $(".parent a").length;
    $(".parent div").width(function(){
        return ($(".parent").width()/count)-5;
    }).css("margin-right","5px");
  });
```

What I would like is to have the last div ignore the `margin-right`

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally you can use the jQuery selectors like `:last`, `:last-child`, `:last-of-type`, and considering you do *not* want an element `:not`.

However you problem here is more to do with when and how you're doing your width calculations and applying the CSS.

I would break this down into a couple of steps, first do the width calculation:

```
var count = $(".parent a").length;

$(".parent div").width(function(){
    return ($(".parent").width()/count)-5;
});
```

Next apply the right margin to all but the *last* div:

```
$(".parent div:not(:last)").css("margin-right","5px");
```

This nearly gets us there, the last bit is just to fill the little gap left over:

```
$(".parent div:last").width(function() {
    return $(".parent div:last").width() + 5;
});
```

And that should do what you want. You can see a working example here - http://jsfiddle.net/jUU86/3/. I'd probably go and replace the margin size with a variable too, just so you don't have to replace multiple locations should you change it.

You can read more about the selectors used here:

- [:last Selector](http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/)
- [:not Selector](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)

Comment: Define `stops it from working`, this slighlty modified example works as I'd expect - http://jsfiddle.net/jUU86/, show us your HTML might make things easier.

Comment: Hard to explain. Here's my code with your JS [link](http://jsfiddle.net/jUU86/1/) and here's what it looks like when the JS works [link](http://jsfiddle.net/jUU86/2/)

Comment: When you apply the CSS is a little off and the way the width calculations is done, this seems to work - http://jsfiddle.net/jUU86/3/

Comment: Fantastic! This works perfect. I really appreciate the effort @Lloyd

Comment: You might want to update your original post Lloyd, to agree with your latest Fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

[`:last-of-type`](http://api.jquery.com/last-of-type-selector/) seem to be what you need. I prefer this over `:last` and `:last-child` because it is more likely that you want to last of the type (a div) and not the last child.

```
$(function () {
    var count = $(".parent a").length;
    $(".parent div").width(function () {
        return ($(".parent").width() / count) - 5;
    });
    $(".parent div:not(:last-of-type)").css("margin-right", "5px");
});
```

Comment: @Adsy See my edit. Does that work? Also, try to be more specific. What does not work?

Comment: The script still works but the margin just removes from all my divs, not just the last one

Answer (score 0):

You could add it on the odd/even numbers : count % 2

Comment: Glad there's a way but this means nothing to me haha, I only do HTML and CSS at an intermediate level